# CSS and JS not loading in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

My css and js files are not loading when i launch my project i already included the link of my files in the stylesheet of my code where it is located. I already trided several methods but it is not working

The components is directly in my public folders directory

public folder contains:

- bower_components
- build
- css
- dist
- documentation
- pages
- plugins

my head.blade.php

```
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>BET ADMIN | Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css'">
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/morris .js/morris.css">
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
  </head>
```

my footer-scripts.blade.php

```
<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

demo.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.mainlayout')

@section('content')

<div>
    HELLO
</div>


@endsection
```

web.php /routes

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/demo', function () {
    return view('demo');
});

Auth::routes();

//Route::get('/demo', 'HomeController@index')->name('demo');

Route::get('demo', 'HomeController@index');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('demo');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project working fine but css and js not working follow this steps

1.Open your file in chrome and press `ctrl + u` then open any link if link open then css working fine error something else

2. use this `{{ asset('css/min.css') }}` or `<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>` [Laravel’s URL::to() vs URL::asset()](https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravels-url-to-vs-url-asset-fd427ed6f7ef)

Comment: What error you got ? can you send me error screen shot

Comment: Remove public from link url 

From
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

To

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to()}}/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
Like This

Comment: It returns an error sir


Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::to(), 0 passed in D:\betAdmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 237 and at least 1 expected (View: D:\betAdmin\resources\views\layouts\partials\head.blade.php) (View: D:\betAdmin\resources\views\layouts\partials\head.blade.php) (View: D:\betAdmin\resources\views\layouts\partials\head.blade.php)

Comment: i am checking this working fine try 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">`

Comment: still not working sir. what happened to my project? i cant proceed

Comment: Can you give me your computer access anydesk i want to check ?@Vince

Comment: i dont know how to do that sir but i can give you my project or my files.

Comment: @Vince Sure send me i want to check

Comment: Got it Mail received wait checking

Comment: I am sending you check you'r email

Comment: not works for me if i edit T_T huhuuhuh . thanks for your help sir

Comment: You miss some class or div in our code please check test.blade.php file and impliment same as this

Comment: @Developer I have a laravel 6 app. The url is opening fine without /public, but the only problem I have is that the website is appearing unstyled. As if the css and js are not loading. I did ctrl + u and this is what I saw. The /public is repeated twice. See image  i.postimg.cc/R00GQkXQ/Untitled.jpg  Someone suggested me to use {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} but where I should put it. This is the repo I am trying to use https://github.com/cmate5614530/inventory-management

Answer (score 0):

check your chrome console through inspect element, probably the system cant find the file path..